# How to create an attribute with Global Scope in Magento 2.4.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

On Admin Panel I need to create a sub-menu in Configuration that has a page. On that page I want to declare a global attribute and add a field that takes the values for this attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think answer from [Magento2 : how to create admin page with configuration fields](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173286/magento2-how-to-create-admin-page-with-configuration-fields?rq=1) can help you.

Nodes `section`, `group` and `field` from `system.xml` has following attributes:

- `showInDefault` - show item in Global scope
- `showInWebsite` - show item in Website scope
- `showInStore` - show item in Store View scope

If you set `showInWebsite` and `showInStore` to `0` the item will show in Global scope

Comment: Thank you. It's exactly what I was looking for.